# Rigidbody slows down when its going up a slope. What can I do?

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I am using unity and I am creating a 3d topdown game. There is no jump feature. The input handling supports only x and z axis player movement. Climbing slopes or  falling from gaps is something I want to happen without certain input.

So,
I have a rigidbody which I move by directly setting its velocity. When it goes up a slope it slows down.

I would like it to keep the same speed.

Now I do it like this:

```
    void Update(){
moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
}

void FixedUpdate(){

MyRB.velocity = moveInput.normalized * runSpeed
}
```

I am using a capsule collider on the rigidbody and a box collider for the slope. The physics materials of the colliders are the default/none (not changed).

Comment: Can you show us both the code you're using to set the velocity (so we can see whether you're driving it up along the slope or flat *into* the slope), and the physics material properties you've set on the capsule and box?

Comment: For me, checking the values for mass and drag in Inspector - Rigidbody, and the amount of force added to the rigidbody upon input allows me to go up slopes etc.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on how you're moving your rigidbody. If you're manually updating the position each frame (using Translate or movePosition, not AddForce), you can apply a physics material to your sphere collider and set the friction somewhere at or slightly below 1. This allows your rigidbody to grip the sloped surface a bit better.